# Subtotal by unique store with multiple sales staff over period

Tags: powerpivot, calc

I am trying to gather various KPI's for salespersons in multiple stores. The goal is to break down store performance into salesperson level.

I am facing an issue when trying to add a hitrate, as this is normally only by store. Number of quotes given / Visitors.

Even though it may not be 100% accurate I still wish to have the KPI by sales person. I am able to do this on a sales person level, but my subtotal for the store is incorrect, as it makes a summation of visitors by sales persons.

Monthly period is to be considered to as sales persons comes and goes throughout the period. Example of what I wish for a Subtotal for the measure "Vis". Store X 370 for month 1,2 & 3. For Store Y 395.

[image]

Vis measure = Visitor (Calculation i have tried but gives the wrong result for the store total for the period.)

I have tried various Calculate, Sum, max functions, but nothing seems to provide the result I need.

I hope that someone might be able to help me get along with this.

Example data tables is link as shown below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeRhe.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the `Vis` measure supposed to represent?

Comment: Please post your data model. We need to see relationships between your tables.

Comment: Hi Rado: Not sure how to post the datamodel. But the relation ship is:

Comment: Table Visitors: [Store]&[MONTH] linked to Table qoutation: [Store]&[MONTH]

Comment: In powerpivot window, select diagram view, and take a schreenshot of your data diagram. It should look similar to the pictures in this article: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/excel_power_pivot/excel_power_pivot_data_model.htm

Comment: I have updated the request description with a picture of the relationship key i have used.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a case where the `HASONVALUE` function would be useful.

The idea being that you would the result of that function in an if to determine if you are calculating at your sales person level or a the store level which should contain multiple salespersons.  Thus you would have two different calculations, one for the sales person and store combination, and one for the Store level.

Example would be sometime like the following, in this example I am assuming you have a sales person table:

```
Measure:= IF( HASONEVALUE( Salesperson[Sales Person] ),
          [Vis],
          [Measure for subtotal]
)
```

[Measure for Subtotal] would just being the calculation that you want for your store total.

Of course if you filter to just a single sales person, then the totals for the store will just match that sales person.